# Ocultar Linkbutton si una columa tiene valor 0 o null

Tags: c#

Una consulta como puedo hacer que en un gridview asp.net se oculte un linkbutton si cierta columna venga en valor cero o null.

He intentado con este codigo, pero no me funciona.

````
    protected void GridView11_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
        {
            //LinkButton lnkbtn = sender as LinkButton;
            LinkButton lnkbtn = e.Row.FindControl("LinkButton31") as LinkButton;
            GridViewRow gvrow = lnkbtn.NamingContainer as GridViewRow;
          
            //getting userid of particular row
            string Revision = (GridView11.DataKeys[gvrow.RowIndex].Values[3].ToString());

            if (Revision == "")
            {
                
                    lnkbtn.Visible = false;
            }
            ```
````

Answer (score 1):

Para que no sea visible:

```
linkButton.Visible = false;
```

Para desactivarlo por completo:

```
linkButton.Enabled = false;
```

Ahora, en tu condicional, solo estas mencionando en la ocasión de que esté vacío.
Recordemos que vacío no es igual a null, además 0 es otra opción.
Para ello ocupamos OR o ||, lo que nos deja comparar más condiciones.
Si no me equivoco, debería ser algo como esto

```
if (Revision == "" || Revision == NULL || Revision == 0)
{
    lnkbtn.Visible = false;
}
```